# Print all the below lines once match is found

Tags: shell-script

I have a file 
a1.txt like this:

```
  a.log.54
  a.log.56
  a.log.57
  a.log.58
  a.log.59
  a.log.110
  a.log.113
  a.log.114
  a.log.115
  a.log.116
  a.log.117
  a.log.118
  a.log.119
  a.log.120
  a.log.121
  a.log.122
  a.log.112
  a.log.123
  a.log.124
  a.log.125
  a.log.126
  a.log.128
  a.log.129
  a.log.130
  a.log.131
  a.log.132
  a.log.133
  a.log.134
  a.log.135
  a.log.136
  a.log.127
  a.log.137
  a.log.139
  a.log.140
```

a2.txt

```
  a.log.124
  a.log.125
```

I need to match first entrie of  a2.txt into a1.txt and print all the below lines once the match is found.

```
  a.log.124
  a.log.125
  a.log.126
  a.log.128
  a.log.129
  a.log.130
  a.log.131
  a.log.132
  a.log.133
  a.log.134
  a.log.135
  a.log.136
  a.log.127
  a.log.137
  a.log.139
  a.log.140
```

Comment: Below what? `a.log.124` or `a.log.125`? Or both? Can `a.log.124` appear *after* `a.log.125`? Is it enough to just print all lines that are after `a.log.124`? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: print all lines from first entry of a2.txt file.. sorry for not mentioning clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` script should work. Set the first line from `a2.txt` into a variable, say, `trigger` and immediately start processing the next file using `nextfile`. Start printing from the `a1.txt` from the point a record matches `trigger`

```
awk 'first{trigger=$0; nextfile}; 
    !first && $0 == trigger{start=1}; 
    start' first=1 a2.txt first=0 a1.txt
```

Comment: `NR==1{trigger=$0;nextfile}$2==trigger … a2.txt a1.txt` is enough.

Comment: @costas, you may recall Stephane pointing out to you in a comment that `NR == 1` or more generally `NR == FNR` don't work as intended when the first file has no records in it

Comment: For your reference `NR==FNR` is not `NR==1` and in case `no records in first file` will print nothing

Comment: @Costas, `NR == 1` causes the first record of second file to qualify when the first file is empty, which nine times out of ten is not the intended behaviour. Compare the output from `awk 'NR ==1' a2.txt a1.txt` with `awk 'first' first=1 a2.txt first=0 a1.txt`

Comment: What is `nine times out of ten`? In case empty *a2.txt* script read first line from *a1.txt* then try to get `nextfile` ==> get nothing so exit without any prints. Suppose that *print nothing* is expected behavior for empty pattern.